# Code is breaking Eclipse Compiler

Tags: java, eclipse, lambda, compilation, java-8

In the course of going too far playing around with lambda expressions, I created the following code:

```
 Supplier<Map<String, Function<UserNetworkEntry, Boolean>>> _groupBuilder = () -> {Arrays.stream(UserType.values())
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(
                    value -> value.toString(),
                    value -> (UserNetworkEntry entry) -> entry.userType == value)))
            .putAll(_usersModel._users.stream()
                    .map(user -> user.organization)
                    .distinct()
                    .collect(Collectors.toMap(
                            organization -> organization, 
                            organization -> entry -> entry.organization.equals(organization))));};
        System.notAPartOfTheSystem.println("Hm");
        int word = "String";
```

As you can probably see by the last two lines, this really, really should not compile. The problem is that it does: According to Eclipse (Neon), the above code type-checks, compiles and even runs. (Run-time behavior is also odd; the method up to the `_groupBuilder=` line executes, but then the method quietly returns without executing any further code... no error is thrown. What's more, I've found I can copy-and-paste that code anywhere, and will get the same behavior.

(Btw, best not to worry about what the code is trying to do. I know it's awful, it's just something I was playing around with.)

I'm pretty sure I've discovered a bug in Eclipse/the Java Compiler, but I'd like to know more about what's going on here. In particular, Eclipse's syntax checking still does some stuff for statements after it "gives up" - it will still recognize unmatched parenthesis, for instance, just nothing in the domain of the type checker.

Can anyone explain what is happening here?

Comment: For me, it says at `value -> (UserNetworkEntry entry) -> entry.userType == value)))` that a semicolon is needed, and indeed, the brackets seem 1 too many... And Eclipse is quite good at messing stuff up when confused...

Comment: @ppeterka That sounds like what a sane compiler would say. What version of Eclipse are you on?

Comment: I tried [Ideone](http://ideone.com/v7Sm3H)...  I'm shy to run arbitrary code on my own PC :)

Comment: `javac` correctly raises an error. Looking at it with the ASM bytecode view (in eclipse), it just ignores the entire thing.

Comment: @JornVernee Just to make sure, does that mean you see the same behavior I do in Eclipse? If so, thanks for checking out the bytecode - I was curious about that

Comment: It compiles and runs, yes. I also looked at it with a `javap -c` and it doesn't seem to be include in the `.class` file. Unless both those tool filter it out. I think Eclipse just skips it.

Comment: @JornVernee Hmm. For mine it ran the method up to that line (it was a constructor), and even returned an apparently valid instance.

Comment: Looks like the whole thing is caused by an extra parenthesis at `entry.userType == value)))` <-- with 2 here, everything starts to fail, at it should. You can safely raise a bug ticket at Eclipse (maybe there's already one for it).

Comment: @Tunaki Guess I'll have to set up an account with them. :) Thanks!

Comment: After adding imports and an empty class UserNetworkEntry I see Eclipse reporting 4 syntax errors and a type error. Would be good if anyone who can reproduce would show a complete source file here.

Comment: I was mislead by the name `_groupBuilder` which in the coding conventions that I know of indicates a field. Pasting the snippet into an empty class indeed triggers syntax errors. If, however, I paste the snippet into the body of a method, the problem can be reproduced. Simplifying examples is always good, oversimplifying can create a lot of confusion ... Have you created the bug report yet?

Comment: @StephanHerrmann Not yet, was busy over the weekend. I'll set up an account and do that today.